# How to properly install Erlang, Elixir and mix on a server?

Tags: linux, erlang, elixir, phoenix-framework

In order to deploy Elixir/Phoenix app I need to install Erlang, Elixir and mix on a server, correct? I haven't found any straightforward way to do that, especially the laterst versions. How can I do it? In Ubuntu or CentOS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you done any research?

```
wget https://packages.erlang-solutions.com/erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i erlang-solutions_1.0_all.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install esl-erlang
sudo apt-get install elixir
```

Comment: Also you can compile Erlang/OTP then Elixir from the source. See https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/maint/HOWTO/INSTALL.md and https://github.com/elixir-lang/elixir .

Answer (score 2):

I don't generally like the above approach - for Elixir we use something called Distillery to create a release, we then package this release up as an RPM.

When you do it this way all that matters is the version of erlang you built the RPM with, `erts` is packaged with your RPM and you don't need to install it directly on the server. A "standalone" release as it were.

We do it this way so we are not restricted by the packages a distro maintainer such as RedHat has deemed "latest". All we do is update our docker RPM builder with the right version of erlang/elixir and rebuild using distillery.

EDIT:

Forgot to give you a link to distillery here: https://github.com/bitwalker/distillery

Comment: Far better to use distillery; smaller binary footprint and also a lot more secure than deploying the entire Erlang/Elixir development stack to a server.